# Why 2d matrix built with grid works differently than same 2d matrix built with nested arrays using new Array()

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, grid

I'm trying to avoid hardcoding 2d matrix grids by using JavaScript `new Array()`. 
In theory, it works, but in practice, I receive a bug. [While a hardcoded grid swaps nearest gems correctly, the `new Array` method swaps them almost randomly with the same code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIUAq.png)

```js
me.tileGrid = new Array(6).fill(new Array(6).fill(null));
 /* The upper code is potentially scalable, but it doesn't work same */
 me.tileGrid = [
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [null, null, null, null, null, null]
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is usage of `fill()`. When you will an array with objects(reference type) then each element refer to the same value in memory. According to MDN

> The `fill()` method changes all elements in an array to a **static value**, from a start index (default 0) to an end index (default array.length).

The above "static value" means that first an array `Array(6).fill(null)` is create and that same is added to the main array six times. Means that if you will change one of them all will change.

The below snippet is the proof for above discussion

```js
const x = new Array(6).fill(new Array(6).fill(null));
console.log(x[0] === x[1])
```

You can use spread operator and then use `map()` and also note that you don't need use `new` with array. `new Array` and `Array` are same

```js
const x = [...Array(6)].map(x => Array(6).fill(null))
console.log(x[0] === x[1])
```